# Telethon How do I get channel messages?

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

Python Telethon

I need to receive messages from the channel

Error:

> >>> client.get_message_history(-1001143136828)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "messages.py", line 23, in 
    total, messages, senders = client.get_message_history(-1001143136828)

File "/Users/kosyachniy/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/telegram_client.py", line 548, in get_message_history
    add_mark=True

KeyError: 1143136828

Answer (score 0):

Error in library

Need to update: `pip install telethon --upgrade`